# Ошибка 422 при работе с fetch

Tags: javascript, html, api, объекты, fetch

Не понимаю, почему вылетает ошибка 422. Вот мой код для запроса:

```
function data() {
let self = this;
self.apiAdd = api;
self.add = function (newData) {
        fetch(self.apiAdd, {method: 'POST'})
            .then(fulfilled => fulfilled.json())
            .then(fulfilled => {
                console.log('Успех', newData);
            })
            .catch(error => console.log('Причина ошибки: ' + error));
    }
}
```

Код для сбора данных:

```
finalAdd.addEventListener('click', function () {
let newPerson = {
        Name: name.value,
        Email: email.value,
    };

    let newPersonJson = JSON.stringify(newPerson);

    new data().add(newPersonJson);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

предположу что проблема в том, что Вы передаёте `newData`, но при `POST` запросе никуда их не указываете, а `fetch` необходим параметр `body`. Укажите его в `fetch`:

```
fetch(self.apiAdd, {
    method: 'POST', 
    body: newData, 
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
})...
```

Comment: Я попробовала, но это почему-то не помогает

Comment: headers: {
                Accept:'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              }

Comment: @Anna попробуйте такой header указать

Comment: Тоже не подходит(